# Are there studies on random walks on orderable groups?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, soft-question, random-walk

This is like a soft question I guess, I'm wondering whether there are studies done on random walks on orderable groups. Are there?

Comment: Like random walks which somehow use the order (the order which you give it, a particular group can have many different orders)? I don't really see a connection

Comment: I'm doing like a class project on random walks and I read about orderable groups before so I thought if there is some paper about it then it would be easier for me to understand and the topic would look cool.

Comment: I don't think the ordering on a group really says anything about random walks. Maybe there could be interesting questions to ask; like can random walks spend more time in the positive cone with higher probability than negative cone? What is the dependence on generating sets and the ordering? Etc I bet questions like this could lead to some toy projects